# Query difficulties

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem, my work database administrator told me that I can no longer create tables, I used the following example to create a table with the following specifications, I would like to know if there is any way to do the same without need to create a new table, but use an existing one. Thank you :)

```
CREATE TABLE cc_aged_cxc_E_08 AS
SELECT *
FROM cc_aged_cxc_08
WHERE tipo = 'Equipos';

CREATE TABLE cc_aged_cxc_S_08_1 AS
SELECT trx_number, trx_date, SUM(saldo_func) AS suma_saldo_func
FROM cc_aged_cxc_S_08
GROUP BY trx_number, trx_date;
```

I tried some update but didnt work.

Comment: Well, it depends on what privileges you do have. Can you create a **view**? Perhaps a **materialized view**?

Comment: can you use with statements (common table expressions?) instead  are these tables used multiple times? or just once as part of your processes...

Comment: Your DBA is right to block this kind of thing. A table that begins as a SELECT query should probably always have been a View.

Comment: "I have a problem, my work database administrator told me that I can no longer create tables" My initial thought is that appears to be because you are randomly creating tables when you do not need to and you should be using a query. In this, your DBA is probably correct and you should just use `SELECT` queries to query data and the problem is your previous behaviour and not the (sensible) restrictions imposed by your DBA.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the tables generated are throw away to begin with.  Meaning their use does not extend beyond the scope of these two queries.  If subsequent queries rely on the tables/data then no as the tables will not exist as it's temporary in all of the following.

Using common table expresisons would be one way; but the data only persists while executing:

```
With cc_aged_cxc_E_08 AS (
SELECT *
FROM cc_aged_cxc_08
WHERE tipo = 'Equipos'),

cc_aged_cxc_S_08_1 AS (
SELECT trx_number, trx_date, SUM(saldo_func) AS suma_saldo_func
FROM cc_aged_cxc_S_08
GROUP BY trx_number, trx_date)

SELECT * FROM cc_aged_cxc_S_08_1
```

Using them as subqueries would be another.

```
-- cc_aged_cxc_S_08_1
SELECT trx_number, trx_date, SUM(saldo_func) AS suma_saldo_func
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM cc_aged_cxc_08
      WHERE tipo = 'Equipos') as cc_aged_cxc_E_08
GROUP BY trx_number, trx_date;
```

However, the cc_aged_Cxc_S_08_1 doesn't exist and instead fo selecting from it you'd use the above query.

Another way is to just combine the needed queries and issue one query.

```
SELECT trx_number, trx_date, SUM(saldo_func) AS suma_saldo_func
FROM cc_aged_cxc_08
WHERE tipo = 'Equipos'
GROUP BY trx_number, trx_date
```

Lastly, intead of creating the tables automatically can they just "Exist" and you insert into them.  THen you're not creating the tables, you're just using them as needed.  But why create tables/use tables in this manner if you can just select the needed data when you need it?